# Format string for int32_t?

Tags: c

What format string works for `int32_t` from `<stdint.h>`?

I'm trying to print values and what I found is that I am supposed to be using:

```
("... %" PRId32 "...\n", value)
```

from `<inttypes.h>` but all I get is the usual '`format %d expects argument of type int, but argument 2 has type int32_t`' message.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int32_t variable = 99;
printf("Value: %" PRId32 "\n", variable);
```

The regular format strings don't work with it. So which format string can I use?

Edit 1: I have edited it since there was lot of misunderstanding; I have included both headers.

Edit 2: Adding the actual function (omitting the includes and dynamic allocation; everything in there will be allocated):

```
struct stuff {int32_t * array[3];}

printf("Value: %" PRId32 "\n", stuff->array[0]);
```

Edit 3: And like that the error was in something entirely different. The `array` should not have had `*` in front of it.

Comment: What platform and compiler are you using?

Comment: Add this: `#include <inttypes.h>`

Comment: @Arash I wanted to start writing this as an answer when I saw your comment coming in. It is the solution: http://ideone.com/OlOY0r

Comment: I'm not 100% convinced that's the solution: http://ideone.com/RoTgpv

Comment: @SouravGhosh - Ah, my point is that if the OP were missing that header, he/she would get very obvious compiler warnings/errors.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Right, makes sense, removed the comment. :)

Comment: @Arash:The warning message let's assume OP very well included `inttypes.h` already.

Comment: Perhaps `<stdint.h>` is missing and the compiler is referring to  `int32_t` as a  yet to be defined type.

Comment: I actually get an error (gcc 5.4) when I don't include the `inttypes.h` because of the `PRId32`.  But the OP never mentioned their observation(error/warning/...).

Comment: Post  a complete compilable version of the problem including `main()` and `#include` used.  Enough so we know _other_ portions of code are not messing with the macros, etc.

Comment: I have edited it. I have already had all the inludes and what i have shown is literary the example. In my actual program i get the values off of an array of int32_t's -

Comment: what about "%hd"?

Comment: Same %hd still gives me warnings.

Comment: `PRId32` is then defined wrong on your system.  What is `printf("%d %d %d  <%s>\n", INT_MIN,INT_MAX, (int) sizeof(int), PRId32);`

Comment: If `PRId32` (or the complier) is amiss, code can use `printf("Value: %ld\n", (long) variable);`   -- I'm also hoping code does not have `int32_t` defined some place else in some non-standard fashion.

Comment: The output is -2147483648 2147483647 4

Comment: Okey this is actually weird. When i put the code into the main it works. But while in my function it gives me off warnings. This is the code (the structure will be allocated on the heap):
' struct stuff { int32_t * array[3]; } 
printf("Value: %" PRId32 "\n", stuff->array[0])'

Comment: ... Then post the complete function and not just pieces like `struct stuff { int32_t * array[3]; }` and the original post.  Post enough so we may compile.

Comment: I have added it in edit. The problems seems to appear only when printing from teh array. I can print the value with %d, but i can't use the actuall value (i need to use the full size of int32 and have no warnings since it is school project and we compile with werror)

Comment: `struct stuff {int32_t * array[3];}

printf("Value: %" PRId32 "\n", stuff->array[0]);` is not valid c code for a variety of reasons.  Multiple times complete code has been requested of OP and only followed up with uncompilable snippets.  Unclear why OP does not post clear examples of problem code.

Comment: @chux: Inclusion of `<inttypes.h>` is supposed to guarantee inclusion of `<stdint.h>` as well. No need to do it explicitily if `<inttypes.h>` is already included.

Comment: Your edit says you added a function, yet there is no function to be seen. And the second code snippet with the `#include`s cannot be compiled - you cannot call `printf` like that after a file scope variable definition. Please post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that show the problem.

Comment: @Zerg Overmind: What?! Your `stuff->array[0]` is of type `int32_t *`. All this time you were lying to us about the error message and providing misleading code samples.

Comment: What exactly is not valid about it? It is a defined structure with a single atribute, which is all this function uses. You don't need to see the code for allocation of data for the structure itself.  You know thet i included all 3 libraries neccesary to print the value. This is all that really happens. I acces a structure and read out value of type int32_t

Comment: @Zerg Overmind: One more time: Your `stuff->array[0]` is of type `int32_t *`, not of type `int32_t`. Why are you trying to print a *pointer* through `PRId32` format? Why are you doing this?

Comment: @AnT If OP is troll or not is less relevant to the unclear post. Save time and VTC, UV or DV as you see fit.

Comment: Yes i noticed that error soon after writing it. I wrote that structure few days ago and just now i realised that i am passing pointer to a pointer.  I am not really trolling, just stupid. Thanks for help everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you've misread the error. The actual error is.

```
format %d expects argument of type int , but argument 2 has type int32_t *.
```

Note the `*` at the end. You are passing a pointer where an integer is expected. You have to dereference the pointer as such:

```
printf("Value: %" PRId32 "\n", *stuff->array[0]);
```

Comment: Yes that was the first thing i did, and the program crashed. BUt thank you, you have led me to the answer. The problem was that i the "*" was not supposed to be there since array itself is allocated alongside the structure thus is already a pointer. I was using pointer to a pointer for some reason. , Thank you sir.